# Seeking Feedback on Bash Script Functionality

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Network Scanning: I provided various network ranges (e.g., 192.168.1.0/24) as input and expected the script to perform a basic scan using Nmap, identifying open ports and service versions across the specified range.

Weak Credentials Checking: I tested the script with different usernames and password types (default or custom) and expected it to check for weak passwords across SSH, RDP, FTP, and Telnet services, based on the selected password type.

Vulnerability Analysis: For the full scan option, I tested the script with different network configurations and expected it to utilize Nmap for vulnerability scanning and Searchsploit to search for associated exploits, providing insights into potential vulnerabilities.

Logging and Output: I ran the script with both basic and full scan options and examined the generated output files (e.g., basic_scan.txt, weak_credentials.txt, vulnerabilities.txt). I expected the script to log relevant information accurately and provide clear output for further analysis.

Overall Script Flow: Throughout testing, I observed the script's overall flow and structure, ensuring that each function executed in the intended sequence and produced the expected output. I expected the script to maintain readability and follow best practices for bash scripting.

Question:
Based on the tests conducted and expectations outlined, how can I confirm if the script is working as intended, and are there any improvements or adjustments you would recommend?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define colors for better UI
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
CYAN='\033[0;36m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color




# Function to perform basic scan
basic_scan() {
  echo -e "${YELLOW}Performing basic scan...${NC}"
  nmap -sS -sU --script "banner" -p- "$1" | tee basic_scan.txt
}

# Function to display stage in terminal
display_stage() {
    echo -e "${CYAN}===================================${NC}"
    echo -e "${CYAN}Stage: $1${NC}"
    echo -e "${CYAN}===================================${NC}"
}

# Function to check if user input is valid
validate_input() {
    if [[ $1 =~ ^(Basic|Full)$ ]]; then
        echo -e "${GREEN}$1 scan includes $(get_scan_description $1)${NC}"
        return 0
    else
        echo -e "${RED}Invalid input. Please choose 'Basic' or 'Full'.${NC}"
        return 1
    fi
}

# Function to get scan description
get_scan_description() {
    case $1 in
        "Basic")
            echo "network scanning for service version and weak passwords checks for SSH, RDP, FTP, and TELNET services."
            ;;
        "Full")
            echo "Nmap Scripting Engine (NSE), weak passwords checks, and vulnerability analysis."
            ;;
    esac
}

# Function to scan for weak credentials
scan_weak_credentials() {
    echo -e "${YELLOW}Checking for weak passwords...${NC}"

    # Specify login services to check
    services=("SSH" "RDP" "FTP" "TELNET")

    # Prompt user for username
    read -p "Enter username: " username

    # Prompt user for password type (default or custom)
    while true; do
        read -p "Choose password type: 'default' or 'custom': " password_type
        if [[ "$password_type" == "default" || "$password_type" == "custom" ]]; then
            break
        else
            echo -e "${RED}Invalid input. Please choose 'default' or 'custom'.${NC}"
        fi
    done

    if [ "$password_type" = "default" ]; then
        # Use built-in password list
        password_list=(
            "password123"
            "admin123"
            "qwerty"
        )
    else
        # Use custom password list
        read -p "Enter path to your custom password list: " custom_password_list
        if [ -f "$custom_password_list" ]; then
            password_list=($(<"$custom_password_list"))
        else
            echo -e "${RED}Custom password list not found.${NC}"
            return 1
        fi
    fi

    # Loop through each service
    for service in "${services[@]}"; do
        echo -e "${YELLOW}Checking for weak passwords in $service...${NC}"
        case "$service" in
            "SSH")
                # Check SSH weak passwords
                for password in "${password_list[@]}"; do
                    sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username"@"$network" "exit" >/dev/null 2>&1
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "Weak password found for SSH: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                    fi
                done
                ;;
            "RDP")
                # Check RDP weak passwords
                for password in "${password_list[@]}"; do
                    xfreerdp /u:"$username" /p:"$password" /v:"$network" >/dev/null 2>&1
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "Weak password found for RDP: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                    fi
                done
                ;;
            "FTP")
                # Check FTP weak passwords
                for password in "${password_list[@]}"; do
                    ftp -n "$network" <<EOF >/dev/null 2>&1
                    quote USER "$username"
                    quote PASS "$password"
                    quit
EOF
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "Weak password found for FTP: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                    fi
                done
                ;;
            "TELNET")
                # Check Telnet weak passwords
                for password in "${password_list[@]}"; do
                    echo "open $network" > telnet_commands.txt
                    echo "user $username $password" >> telnet_commands.txt
                    echo "quit" >> telnet_commands.txt
                    telnet "$network" < telnet_commands.txt | grep -q "Welcome" >/dev/null 2>&1
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "Weak password found for Telnet: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                    fi
                done
                ;;
        esac
    done

    echo -e "${GREEN}Weak credentials checked and saved to weak_credentials.txt${NC}"
}



# Function to check weak passwords for a service
check_weak_passwords() {
    local service="$1"
    local username="$2"
    local password_list="$3"

    case "$service" in
        "SSH")
            # Check SSH weak passwords
            while IFS= read -r password; do
                sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username"@"$network" "exit" >/dev/null 2>&1
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "Weak password found for SSH: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                fi
            done < "$password_list"
            ;;
        "RDP")
            # Check RDP weak passwords
            while IFS= read -r password; do
                xfreerdp /u:"$username" /p:"$password" /v:"$network" >/dev/null 2>&1
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "Weak password found for RDP: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                fi
            done < "$password_list"
            ;;
        "FTP")
            # Check FTP weak passwords
            while IFS= read -r password; do
                ftp -n "$network" <<EOF >/dev/null 2>&1
                quote USER "$username"
                quote PASS "$password"
                quit
EOF
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "Weak password found for FTP: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                fi
            done < "$password_list"
            ;;
        "TELNET")
            # Check Telnet weak passwords
            while IFS= read -r password; do
                echo "open $network" > telnet_commands.txt
                echo "user $username $password" >> telnet_commands.txt
                echo "quit" >> telnet_commands.txt
                telnet "$network" < telnet_commands.txt | grep -q "Welcome" >/dev/null 2>&1
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "Weak password found for Telnet: $username:$password" >> weak_credentials.txt
                fi
            done < "$password_list"
            ;;
    esac
}

# Function to map vulnerabilities
map_vulnerabilities() {
    if [ "$1" = "Full" ]; then
        echo -e "${YELLOW}Mapping vulnerabilities...${NC}"

        # Use Nmap to scan for vulnerabilities
        nmap -sV --script vuln "$network" > vulnerabilities.txt

        # Use Searchsploit to search for exploits
        searchsploit --nmap vulnerabilities.txt >> vulnerabilities.txt
    fi
}

# Function to log results
log_results() {
    echo -e "${YELLOW}Logging results...${NC}"

    # Zip results
    if [ "$scan_type" = "Basic" ]; then
        zip -r "$output_directory.zip" weak_credentials.txt built_in_password_list.txt basic_scan.txt
    elif [ "$scan_type" = "Full" ]; then
        zip -r "$output_directory.zip" weak_credentials.txt vulnerabilities.txt
    fi

    echo -e "${GREEN}Results logged and saved to $output_directory.zip${NC}"
}

# Function to display found information
display_results() {
    echo -e "${YELLOW}Results:${NC}"
    if [ "$scan_type" = "Basic" ]; then
        cat basic_scan.txt
    elif [ "$scan_type" = "Full" ]; then
        cat weak_credentials.txt
        if [ -f "vulnerabilities.txt" ]; then
            cat vulnerabilities.txt
        else
            echo -e "${YELLOW}No vulnerabilities found.${NC}"
        fi
    fi
}

# Function to search inside results
search_results() {
    echo -e "${YELLOW}Search inside results:${NC}"
    if [ "$scan_type" = "Basic" ]; then
        grep -irn "$1" basic_scan.txt 
    elif [ "$scan_type" = "Full" ]; then
        if [ -f "vulnerabilities.txt" ]; then
            grep -irn "$1" weak_credentials.txt vulnerabilities.txt
        else
            echo -e "${YELLOW}No vulnerabilities found.${NC}"
        fi
    fi
}

# Main script starts here
# Get user input
display_stage "Getting User Input"
read -p "$(echo -e 'Enter network to scan (e.g., 192.168.1.0/24): ')" network
read -p "$(echo -e 'Enter name for output directory: ')" output_directory
while true; do
    read -p "$(echo -e 'Choose '${YELLOW}'Basic'${NC}' or '${YELLOW}'Full'${NC}' scan: ')" scan_type
    if validate_input "$scan_type"; then
        break
    fi
done

# Perform basic scan if scan_type is Basic
if [ "$scan_type" = "Basic" ]; then
    basic_scan "$network"
fi

# Perform weak credentials scan
display_stage "Weak Credentials"
scan_weak_credentials

# Map vulnerabilities if scan_type is Full
if [ "$scan_type" = "Full" ]; then
    display_stage "Mapping Vulnerabilities"
    map_vulnerabilities "$scan_type"
fi

# Log results
display_stage "Logging Results"
log_results

# Display found information
display_stage "Displaying Found Information"
display_results

# Allow user to search inside results
while true; do
    read -p "$(echo -e 'Search inside results (enter keyword or '${YELLOW}'exit'${NC}' to quit): ')" keyword
    if [ "$keyword" = "exit" ]; then
        break
    else
        search_results "$keyword"
    fi
done

# End of script
```

Comment: [codereview.se] is a better place for this.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing (yes, there are frameworks even for bash unit testing) and ShellCheck are your friends.

Although I'd use some proper programming language it provides libraries that can help you achieve your goal. Python or Go would be good choice.